# how can i solve the error after moving IIS site

Tags: iis

I have a question about move a website from one ISS to another and the error that comes with it.
When I add the new website as a application like to old situation I get the following error msg when I open it.

i have no idea how i can fix this, i look it up on google and stuff but my knowles coding is the great the point me in the right direction. so i hope some of you can help me out to make this work.

the code i get is:

```
Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
Source Error: 


 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 



[IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.]
   Incidentensysteem.Index.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Michel\Documents\Incidentensysteem\Incidentensysteem\Index.aspx.cs:32
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +106
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3785



Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3429.0


**Full Code:**
namespace Incidentensysteem
{
    public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private Klant klant;
        private string medewerkerNaam;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string datumString = "2000-01-01";
            //string datumString = datum.Year + "-" + datum.Month + "-" + datum.Day;
            if (ObjectDataSource3.SelectParameters.Contains(ObjectDataSource3.SelectParameters["Datum"]))
            {
                ObjectDataSource3.SelectParameters["Datum"].DefaultValue = datumString;

            }
            if (ObjectDataSource4.SelectParameters.Contains(ObjectDataSource4.SelectParameters["Datum"]))
                ObjectDataSource4.SelectParameters["Datum"].DefaultValue = datumString;

            //Random random = new Random();
            //LabelIncidentZoeken.Text = random.Next().ToString();
            this.klant = null;
            string v = medewerkerNaam = Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"].Split('\\')[1];
            //this.medewerkerNaam = "Michel";
            if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0)
            {
                ObjectDataSource2.SelectParameters["Klant_ID"].DefaultValue = Request.QueryString[0];
                ObjectDataSource2.DataBind();
                ObjectDataSource3.SelectParameters["Klant_ID"].DefaultValue = Request.QueryString[0];
                ObjectDataSource3.DataBind();
                ObjectDataSource4.SelectParameters["Klant_ID"].DefaultValue = Request.QueryString[0];
                ObjectDataSource4.DataBind();
                ObjectDataSource5.SelectParameters["Klant_ID"].DefaultValue = Request.QueryString[0];
                ObjectDataSource5.DataBind();
                showControls();
            }
            if (TextBoxZoeken.Text.Length > 0)
                zoeken(DropDownListZoeken.SelectedValue, GridView1.SelectedIndex);
```

Comment: Check the code and see what it does on that line first. Nobody can help unless they see that code.

Comment: According to your description and error codes, it seems there is something wrong in the Index Page_Load event. I suggest you could try to use remote debug to remote your IIS web application by using visual studio.  Details, you could refer to below [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-7-5-computer?view=vs-2019).

Comment: I added the code with line 32